Access denied in keycloak.protect() Express node js app
I'm trying to get user info from keycloak with keycloak.protect() middleware, but always get 403 "Access denied".
Keycloak version 24.0.2
I did my own realm and client
My keycloak.json
{
  "realm": "realm",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "bearerOnly": true,
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "tender",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "some secret"
  },
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "policy-enforcer": {
    "credentials": {}
  }
}

index.js
const app: Express = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "mySecret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: memoryStore,
  })
);

app.use(
  keycloak.middleware({
    logout: "/logout",
    admin: "/",
  })
);

app.use("/api/v1", router);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    await sequelize.sync();
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();

router.post("/login", userController.login);
router.get("", keycloak.protect(), userController.get);

Login is working. I get tokens, but get route always returns "Access denied". What should i do in admin console to resolve this
I had tried to play with roles in admin console, but it didnt help

Where are you running keycloak. On a remote instance ? On Docker or via the binary?

@MocktarIssa docker

You need to enable and configure Authorization Services in Keycloak. This involves setting up policies, permissions, resources, and scopes.
Resources: The things you want to protect, such as APIs, web pages, or any other resource. It is the target of API.
Scopes: It is an action, like a read, write, or delete to performed on the resource.
Permission: the association between resources and scopes. It decide to allow or not to access a resource.
Policy: Define the conditions under which access to a resource is granted.
Demo
I will leverage keycloak-nodejs-connect example
I will show username user is 403 error but username admin is not error Access granted to Default Resource.
user

admin

There are many steps,
Please follow me step by step.
Step 1. launching Keycloak v24.2
In here
Step 2. Import nodejs-example realm
{
    "realm": "nodejs-example",
    "enabled": true,
    "sslRequired": "external",
    "registrationAllowed": true,
    "privateKey": "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",
    "publicKey": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCrVrCuTtArbgaZzL1hvh0xtL5mc7o0NqPVnYXkLvgcwiC3BjLGw1tGEGoJaXDuSaRllobm53JBhjx33UNv+5z/UMG4kytBWxheNVKnL6GgqlNabMaFfPLPCF8kAgKnsi79NMo+n6KnSY8YeUmec/p2vjO2NjsSAVcWEQMVhJ31LwIDAQAB",
    "requiredCredentials": [ "password" ],
    "users" : [
        {
            "username" : "user",
            "enabled": true,
            "email" : "sample-user@nodejs-example",
            "firstName": "Sample",
            "lastName": "User",
            "credentials" : [
                { "type" : "password",
                  "value" : "password" }
            ],
            "realmRoles": [ "user" ],
            "clientRoles": {
                "account": ["view-profile", "manage-account"]
            }
        }
    ],
    "roles" : {
        "realm" : [
            {
                "name": "user",
                "description": "User privileges"
            },
            {
                "name": "admin",
                "description": "Administrator privileges"
            }
        ]
    },
    "scopeMappings": [
        {
            "client": "nodejs-connect",
            "roles": ["user"]
        }
    ],
    "clients": [
        {
            "clientId": "nodejs-connect",
            "enabled": true,
            "publicClient": true,
            "baseUrl": "/",
            "adminUrl" : "http://localhost:3000/",
            "baseUrl" : "http://localhost:3000/",
            "redirectUris": [
                "http://localhost:3000/*"
            ],
            "webOrigins": []
        },
        {
            "clientId": "nodejs-apiserver",
            "enabled": true,
            "secret": "secret",
            "redirectUris": [
              "http://localhost:3000/*"
            ],
            "webOrigins": [
              "http://localhost:3000/*"
            ],
            "serviceAccountsEnabled": true,
            "authorizationServicesEnabled": true,
            "authorizationSettings": {
              "resources": [
                {
                  "name": "resource",
                  "type": "urn:nodejs-apiserver:resources:default",
                  "ownerManagedAccess": false,
                  "uris": [
                    "/*"
                  ],
                  "scopes": [
                    {
                      "name": "view"
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "write"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
    ]
}


Result of nodejs-example realm import

In nodejs-apiserver client has default resource with write and view scopes.
I will show this resource can be accessed by admin user.

Step 3. Add admin user
password is 1234

Step 4. Set up  policy

Result of setup policy

Step 5. Set up  permission

Result of setup permission

Step 6. Setup Server
File tree

Save as index.html under view directory
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        li a {
            display: block;
            color: #000;
            padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;

        }

        /* Change the link color on hover */
        li a:hover {
            background-color: #555;
            color: white;
        }

        .nav {
            float: left;
            width: 250px;
        }
        .content {
            margin-left: 270px;

        }
        pre {
            word-wrap: break-word;
            white-space: pre-wrap;
            background-color: #ddd;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">NodeJS Keycloak Example</h1>
<hr/>

<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/protected/resource">Protected Resource</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <h2>Result</h2>
    <pre id="output">
{{result}}
    </pre>

    <h2>Events</h2>
    <pre id="events">
{{event}}
    </pre>
</div>


</body>
</html>

Save as server.js
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect')
const hogan = require('hogan-express')
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')

const app = express()

const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  const host = server.address().address
  const port = server.address().port
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
})

// Register '.mustache' extension with The Mustache Express
app.set('view engine', 'html')
app.set('views', require('path').join(__dirname, '/view'))
app.engine('html', hogan)

// A normal un-protected public URL.

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index')
})

// Create a session-store to be used by both the express-session
// middleware and the keycloak middleware.

const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore()

app.use(session({
  secret: 'mySecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}))

// Provide the session store to the Keycloak so that sessions
// can be invalidated from the Keycloak console callback.
//
// Additional configuration is read from keycloak.json file
// installed from the Keycloak web console.

const keycloak = new Keycloak({
  store: memoryStore
})

// Install the Keycloak middleware.
//
// Specifies that the user-accessible application URL to
// logout should be mounted at /logout
//
// Specifies that Keycloak console callbacks should target the
// root URL.  Various permutations, such as /k_logout will ultimately
// be appended to the admin URL.

app.use(keycloak.middleware({
  logout: '/logout',
  admin: '/',
  protected: '/protected/resource'
}))

app.get('/login', keycloak.protect(), function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    result: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(req.session['keycloak-token']), null, 4),
    event: '1. Authentication\n2. Login'
  })
})

app.get('/protected/resource', keycloak.enforcer(['resource:view', 'resource:write'], {
  resource_server_id: 'nodejs-apiserver'
}), function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    result: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(req.session['keycloak-token']), null, 4),
    event: '1. Access granted to Default Resource\n'
  })
})

package.json
{
  "name": "nodejs-keycloak-example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Example page that demonstrates available keycloak functionality",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Roman Jurkov <winfinit@gmail.com>",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "hogan-express": "^0.5.2",
    "keycloak-connect": "^24.0.2"
  }
}

Step 7. Install dependencies and run it
npm install

node index.js


Step 8. Open by Browser
http://localhost:3000


Step 9. 403 Error for user
Credential
username: user
password: password


Result

Step 10. Access Grant for admin
Credential
username: admin
password: 1234


Result
User admin can access resource without error

This code passed and displayed Access granted message in html
app.get('/protected/resource', keycloak.enforcer(['resource:view', 'resource:write'], {
  resource_server_id: 'nodejs-apiserver'
}), function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    result: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(req.session['keycloak-token']), null, 4),
    event: '1. Access granted to Default Resource\n'
  })
})

Conclusion
So your "tender" resource needs to set up a policy/permission for your specific user.

This was realy helpfull, but i need to use keycloak without ui (only backend), is process the same?

and also can u please show how to get user attributes after middleware

The keycloak-nodejs-connect serves as middleware, utilizing the authentication code flow, which is designed for scenarios where a user logs in through a UI. The process is not same. I recommend using REST API call from backend instead of using keycloak-nodejs-connect.
You can get User attributes by token decoding in here
